# onActivityResult work only in Debug Mode

Tags: android

i have 2 activities that share data between them:

Activity B (child)

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    if (miItem != null){
        Intent data = new Intent();
        Sharable sh = new Sharable(miItem);
        data.putExtra("item",sh);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, data); 
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Sharable is a class that extend Parseable

Activity A (Parent)

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == REQ_DIRECCIONES) //actualizamos la direccion
    {
        if (data != null){
            Sharable sh = (Sharable)data.getExtras().getParcelable("item");
            OElement item = (OElement) sh.getObject();
            //HERE!! "item" is NULL in runtime mode but not in debug mode
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your implementation of `Parcelable`? I'd suggest you try using [`Serializable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html) interface together with [`putExtra(String, Serializable)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.io.Serializable%29) instead.